# is there a wait parameter in PowerShell to allow the script to wait until a command is completed

Tags: powershell

I trying to install a software using Start-Process in PowerShell, I would like for the script to wait until a command is completed before proceeding to the next one. I'm not experienced I tired the script below but it did not work.

`Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Temp\Latitude_5X10_Precision_3550_1.15.0.exe" -ArgumentList "/S" -PassThru`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call is correct, but `-Wait` invariably only tracks the lifetime of the *directly* launched process (`C:\Temp\Latitude_5X10_Precision_3550_1.15.0.exe` in your case).

That is, you're out of luck if the target process itself spawns yet another process in order to perform its task and then *returns before that child process has terminated*.

Additional work is then needed, if even feasible:

- If you know the name of the child process, you can try to find and track it via [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process).
- Alternatively, if you know of an *indirect* sign that the task has completed, such as the existence of a directory or a registry entry, look for that.

---

As an aside: *console*(-subsystem) applications can be invoked *directly* for synchronous (blocking) execution (e.g., `foo.exe bar baz` or `& $fooExePath bar baz`), which is the preferred method, because it connects the application's output streams to PowerShell's streams.